# Why do I only get hair rendered without head in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, error

I'm trying to render my head with some hair but I got only hair to show in render result

I need it with transparent background.

[image]

https://mega.nz/file/FIQXHYaS#FfvUA3HrU18Cpuqyz-jCxjMmVADXrCAfH-qzGshE-mg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the *Particle Properties* tab there is a setting called *Render > Show Emitter*. You probably turned it off by mistake and since the head is the emitter of the particles, it is not rendered now. Just tick the checkbox and the head will be rendered again.

[image: show emitter setting]

The setting is useful when you have a so-called haircap. That's a separate mesh with only the hairstyle on it. Usually, you don't want to render it. So, you can turn it off here for render. The same setting is available for the viewport (*Viewport > Show Emitter*) to hide the emitter in the viewport and only show the particles.